# Delete text *after* cursor in vim (leaving what is under the cursor)

Tags: vim

Let's say I've got this text on a line:

```
myNewFunction(argument); // some junk I don't need
                       ^
                   my cursor
```

What is the fastest way to delete everything after the semicolon (which I'm on). So for example, D will not work, because it deletes the semicolon too. I know I can do lD (move right one, then delete)

Is there a general way to delete *after* cursor though? Ideally I could even do something like Da3 (delete everything three characters after the cursor position)

EDIT: This often happens after I'm finished typing a semicolon and then I press Esc - now my cursor is on the semicolon.

Comment: Why do you think `lD` is not fast enough? `Da3` would be pretty much on par with `3lD`, no? Also, `Da3` is non-standard (has no basis in vim at all), while you can say `$T;D` to delete everything from the last semicolon, `3wD` to delete anything after three words, etc. with standard vim movements.

Comment: Sorry I'm not suggesting to subvert normal vim mappings, I'm assuming there are normal vim mappings that do what I want. When you finish typing and end up as I show above, do you press 'Esc lD'? If that's really the best way, that's fine.

Comment: In fact, maybe I need to *start* my editing more intelligently. For example, start the line with C that way I won't have this extra junk anyway. Although it's too bad if I wanted to *read* that junk while typing, then delete afterwards.

Comment: If you're still in insert mode when you want to delete the rest of the line, `<C-O>D` should do it (and return you back to insert mode). If you want to exit insert mode, either `<C-O>D<Esc>` or `<Esc>lD` should work, but the latter is probably a bit more "normal".

Comment: @Amadan yes that's exactly what I was looking for. Thank you. Now where's the button to magically turn your comment into the accepted answer ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

lol.... Okay, I'll type it up.

So - If you're in insert mode, `<C-O>` switches it off for one command only, without moving the cursor. So if you do `<C-O>D`, you will delete the rest of the line and get dropped back into insert mode.

If you are in normal mode, `lD` should be fast enough.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's not posible without mappings or repeating a substitution.

If you don't have problem 'repeating' a substitution, you can do a first substitution:

```
:s/;\ze.*$//
```

And then, repeat it using `&` is one key stroke, but you nead to make the substitution and then, repeat it. Just to be clear, pressing `&` repeats the last substitution. It's like the `.` command but only for substitutions

Answer (score 0):

Try to create a function and use it with a normal mapping.

This gets character under current cursor position and instead of `D` use `C` that sets insert mode and lets us to put the character saves previosly:

```
function! DeleteUntilEOL()
    let c = getline('.')[col('.')-1]
    execute 'normal C' . c 
endfunction
```

Now create the mapping:

```
:nnoremap <leader>D :call DeleteUntilEOL()<CR>
```